# Not able to add product in category

Tags: magento2, categories

I am adding products in newly created subcategory. However I am getting an error **"The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists."** for all the products, after saving that category. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the URL of your product make it different URL